# How to get a string in regex and delete other after matching the string

Tags: php, regex, instagram-api

my input is following

1 blah blah blah @username_. sblah sblah sblah

the output I need is following 
username_.

for now, I make this expression

`^.*\@([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_]+)$`

which working in following

1 blah blah blah @username_.

but if I use it for the full line it's not working

so its get the user and delete before the user 
but how I can make it delete the rest once it gets the user

Note I use regex101 for testing if you have a better tool please write it below.

Comment: It will always end with _.?

Comment: You should post the actual code. And post some of the failed examples and what output they gave and what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern uses `^$` which means it needs a full match, your pattern is only partial.
By adding a `.*` it becomes a full regex and it matches as expected.

```
"/^.*\@([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_]+).*$/"
```

https://3v4l.org/i4pVd

Another way to do it is to use a partial regex like this.
It skips anything up to the @ and then captures all to a dot

```
$str = "1 blah blah blah @username_. sblah sblah sblah";
preg_match("/.*?\@(.*?\.)/", $str, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

https://3v4l.org/mvBYI

Answer (score 0):

To match the username in you example data, you could [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and omit the `$` to assert the position at the end of the string as in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWcfwy/1). Note that you don't have to escape the `@` and the dot and underscore in the character class.

To get the username in you example data, you could also use:

`@\K[\w.]+`

**That would match**

- `@` Match literally
- `\K` Forget what was previously matched
- `[\w.]+` Match 1+ times a word character or a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iEuKs2/1)

```
$re = '/@\K[\w.]+/';
$str = '1 blah blah blah @username_. sblah sblah sblah @test';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // username_.
```

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/T0CJM)